# Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget treeActual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type"TextFormField"> Which: means none were found

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, widget-test-flutter, bloc-test

Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
Actual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type "TextFormField">
Which: means none were found but one was expected

Facing above issue.

i have added this key in view screen
->
TextFormField(
key: Key("searchControllerKey")
),

And using that key in widget testing in flutter.

final searchControllerKey = find.byKey(ValueKey("searchControllerKey"));
expect(searchControllerKey, findsOneWidget);

After this still i'm facing above one error

final searchControllerKey = find.byKey(ValueKey("searchControllerKey"));
expect(searchControllerKey, findsOneWidget);